# Internet Explorer 8 - SCRIPT1010 error with Youtube JSONC API

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, youtube, youtube-api

I'm using the [youtube JSONC API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_jsonc) to get last videos from channels. Problems come when I try to get the **default** player link

`"player":{
              "default":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v\u003dhYB0mn5zh2c",
            "mobile":"https://m.youtube.com/details?v\u003dhYB0mn5zh2c"
         },`

that key returns a SCRIPT1010 error. Is there a way to call it without having problems in IE8?

Comment: Remove the trailing comma after the last property definition.

Comment: Sorry, probably I've not explained properly. That snippet is taken from the JSON code returned by Youtube.

THe code I'm using is 

`var obj = {
  title : news.title,
          link : news.player.default,
          s_link : news.player.default
         };`

Comment: `SCRIPT1010 == Identifier expected.` --> the most probably reason is that you've a trailing comma in an object literal after the last property, and IE is waiting for one more property definition, instead it finds `}`, hence an error. This happens only in IEs < 9. If the comma is in a JSON string, just remove it before parsing.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I remove the last trailing comma from the returned JSON code?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with a faster solution. Since the object has also the mobile link that obviously has the same video ID, I use this code to get the video link:

```
var link = news.player.mobile.replace('m.youtube', 'www.youtube').replace('/details?', '/watch?');
```

Hope this could help in future